# Live Calendar using Javascript ( not any other language)

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I have a basic design for the event calendar created using just html and css. Event date has been given the different background and whenever the user hovers over it, the event pops out. I have all this. 
My real problem is to have a live calendar which updates itself (date) without changing the current design.
No other languages will be used otherthan javascript.

please help me.

```css
table{
 font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

td.effect {
 width:23px;
 height:23px;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:none;   }
table, td.header {
 background: #fff;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
}
td.event {
 border-radius:50%;
 background-color:#A29F9F;
 border:none;
 }
 td.event:hover {
  color:#F7EFEF;
  background-color:#000000;
   }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body></body>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" ><table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="1"  style="border-radius: 10px;" width="200" height="170" border="2" >
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="header" style="border-radius: 10px; border:none;" colspan="7"><strong>Event Calendar</strong></td>
    </tr>
 <tr align="center"> 
 <td class="header" style="border-radius: 10px; border:none;" colspan="7"><strong>June 2017</strong></td></tr>
    <tr  align="center" bgcolor="black" style="color: #fff; font-style: bold;">
      <td class="effect"  width="15">S</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="15">M</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">T</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">W</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">T</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">F</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">S</td>
    </tr>
    <tr   align="center">
      <td class="effect"><img  style="" src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="effect" ><img  src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="effect" ><img  src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="effect" ><img  src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="event" >01</td>
      <td class="effect" >02</td>
      <td class="effect" >03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr   align="center">
      <td class="effect" >04</td>
      <td class="effect" >05</td>
      <td class="effect" >06</td>
      <td class="effect" >07</td>
      <td class="effect" >08</td>
      <td class="effect" >09</td>
      <td class="effect" >10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  align="center">
      <td class="effect" >11</td>
      <td class="effect" >12</td>
      <td class="effect" >13</td>
      <td class="effect" >14</td>
      <td class="effect" >15</td>
      <td class="effect" >16</td>
      <td class="effect" >17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="effect" >18</td>
      <td class="effect" >19</td>
      <td class="effect" >20</td>
      <td class="effect" >21</td>
      <td class="effect" >22</td>
      <td class="event" title= " This is just an example of hovering effect"  >23</td>
      <td class="effect" >24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  align="center">
      <td class="effect" >25</td>
      <td class="effect" >26</td>
      <td class="effect" >27</td>
      <td class="effect" >28</td>
      <td class="effect" >29</td>
      <td class="effect" >30</td>
      <td class="effect" ><img src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: what action does the user take and what does the javascript do? for instance, when the user clicks on a date it is highlighted like July 01 and July 23 as in this calendar. Or, if the date is highlighted when clicked it willl lose its highlight

Comment: javascript is for the live calendar which shows the current date,and the dates 1 and 23 have the events and when the user hovers over it, events pops out just like in the case of date "23". that;s it, Now i want my calendar to autto update it current date>

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I changed HTML enough so you can get the idea. Since the original example showed a July calendar and today is June I changed the month name on the calendar, but I didn't rearrange the dates on the grid.

I added the .today class in the CSS. I'm not completely sure if this is what the OP is asking for.

```js
dates = ["2017-07-01","2017-07-23","2017-08-08","2017-07-12","2017-06-04","2017-06-29"]; // here are all your selected events

curYear = "2017"; // when displaying the calendar, set the year and month of the current calendar
curMo = "06";


dl = dates.length;

cells = document.getElementsByClassName('effect'),
cl = cells.length;


for(di=0; di<dl; di++){
 darray = dates[di].split("-");
 if ( curYear == darray[0] && curMo == darray[1]){
  for(ci=0; ci<cl; ci++) {
      cur = cells[ci];
      if(cur.innerHTML == darray[2]){
    cur.className += " event"; // you can take out the '+' if you want
   }
  }
 }
}

dateObj = new Date();
todayMonth = pad(dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1); //months from 1-12
todayDay = pad(dateObj.getUTCDate());
todayYear = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

if ( curYear == todayYear && curMo == todayMonth){
  for(i=0; i<cl; i++) {
      cur = cells[i];
      if(cur.innerHTML == todayDay){
    cur.className += " today"; // you can take out the '+' if you want
   }
  }
 }

function pad(x){ // add leading zeros
 return (x.length < 2)? "0" + x: x;
 }
```

```css
table{
 font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

td.effect {
 width:23px;
 height:23px;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:none;   }
table, td.header {
 background: #fff;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #d3d3d3); 
}
td.event {
 border-radius:50%;
 background-color:#A29F9F;
 border:none;
 }
 td.event:hover {
  color:#F7EFEF;
  background-color:#000000;
   }
      td.today { background-color: #9ff; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body></body>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" ><table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="1"  style="border-radius: 10px;" width="200" height="170" border="2" >
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="header" style="border-radius: 10px; border:none;" colspan="7"><strong>Event Calendar</strong></td>
    </tr>
 <tr align="center"> 
 <td class="header" style="border-radius: 10px; border:none;" colspan="7"><strong>June 2017</strong></td></tr>
    <tr  align="center" bgcolor="black" style="color: #fff; font-style: bold;">
      <td class="effect"  width="15">S</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="15">M</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">T</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">W</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">T</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">F</td>
      <td class="effect"  width="18">S</td>
    </tr>
    <tr   align="center">
      <td class="effect"><img  style="" src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="effect" ><img  src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="effect" ><img  src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="effect" ><img  src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
      <td class="effect" >01</td>
      <td class="effect" >02</td>
      <td class="effect" >03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr   align="center">
      <td class="effect" >04</td>
      <td class="effect" >05</td>
      <td class="effect" >06</td>
      <td class="effect" >07</td>
      <td class="effect" >08</td>
      <td class="effect" >09</td>
      <td class="effect" >10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  align="center">
      <td class="effect" >11</td>
      <td class="effect" >12</td>
      <td class="effect" >13</td>
      <td class="effect" >14</td>
      <td class="effect" >15</td>
      <td class="effect" >16</td>
      <td class="effect" >17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="effect" >18</td>
      <td class="effect" >19</td>
      <td class="effect" >20</td>
      <td class="effect" >21</td>
      <td class="effect" >22</td>
      <td class="effect" title= " This is just an example of hovering effect"  >23</td>
      <td class="effect" >24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  align="center">
      <td class="effect" >25</td>
      <td class="effect" >26</td>
      <td class="effect" >27</td>
      <td class="effect" >28</td>
      <td class="effect" >29</td>
      <td class="effect" >30</td>
      <td class="effect" ><img src="logo without bakgorund.png" width="15" height="15" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: @AbrarEAnjum BRO! your question was extremely unclear. If you'd like to to highlight the date today, then that can't be shown on a July calendar because today is in June. I changed your HTML a little bit, but I didn't match up dates with correct days.  It is now highlighting dates in June as well as the current date. I edited html, css and Javascript

Comment: exactly bro!! it was my mistake, by mistake i made it "july" instead of "june", sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: Yup bro understood, its your time zone, but how do i set my time zone (India) which is UTC +5.30